# C code, where i have a value of an integer variable and after a pre-increment operation i need to get the output

Tags: c, pre-increment

```
i=2;

i= ++i + ++i + ++i;

printf(i)
```

Please give the output with explanation?
The answer I'm getting is **12** but it should be **13**.

Comment: I strongly advise you to look for already existing questions before writing your own one. Use Google for search.

Comment: There should be a script to detect this repetitive gunge and auto-reply, (and on C++ too).  It might be nice if, just occasionally, the var name changed from 'i'.  It's never 'j', or 'index', or 'banana' - it's always 'i'.

Comment: Unfortunalely we *do* have questions about `j++`, as well as about a, b, c, p, k, s, u, v, x, y, and z. And both `++` and `--`, and both pre and post operators. [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=url%3a%22http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2f949433%2f*%22)

Answer (score 5):

The behavior of your code is *undefined* according to the C standard, as you are not allowed to use the preincrement operator more than once within the same expression. The output can be anything whatsoever.

See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) for a more comprehensive treatment of the topic.

Answer (score -4):

Though the behaviour is undefined, IN UR CASE IT HAS BEEN EXECUTED AS, CONSIDERING THE PARSING IS FROM left, i = 5 + 4 + 3 = 12

For explanation, 
    i = (++i) + (++i) + (++i) 
Now i = 2, so first ++i expands as 3 and i becomes i=3
    i = (++i) + (++i) + 3

Now i = 3, so ++i expands as 4 and i becomes i=4
    i = (++i) + 4 + 3

Now i = 4, so first ++i expands as 4 and i becomes i=5
    i = 5 + 4 + 3